# Hacked bitcoin account.

Tags: wallet, attack

I believe that my account was hacked: a "send" transaction occurred on my account an hour ago and I lost $62 without my raising any transaction. The transaction is still unconfirmed, how do reverse it and get my money back ? Standing by. 
Recipient address-https://blockchain.info/address/18VhGJQgvYVpGLfZPJ1wu85JDAJ8UU6A62
Transaction hash code - https://blockchain.info/tx/ae97308ffd3e460ec4d928d5309479351220b30811d7e02f2a571e23d38e48d2

Once more, I did not make this transaction,and $62 disappeared from my account. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This transaction has now been confirmed and cannot be reversed.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. What do I do to reverse the transaction if this attack happens again?

Comment: In theory you can attempt a [double spend](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Double-spending).  In practice it is unlikely to work.  The design goal is for Bitcoin transactions to be completely irreversible - double-spend is a weakness in that, but there are other safeguards intended to make it difficult to successfully pull off.  In effect, once the attacker has made the transaction, it is already too late.  You should focus instead on securing your systems so that they do not get access to your wallet in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoin transactions cannot be reversed - unless you are sending coins to someone you know by mistake and they are willing to send it back - which in itself is also relatively unlikely.

If someone has sent money from your account without your knowledge, then they have got hold of your private keys. What wallet did you use? Is it local on your machine? Is it online - in which case you may have not set a complicated enough password.

Sorry about your loss but you need to make sure your wallet is secure in order to prevent this from happening again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the UK based exchange exmo.com could know the person who took your bitcoin. Now the initially low value is about $3,000 and it can further increase.

I entered 18VhGJQgvYVpGLfZPJ1wu85JDAJ8UU6A62 into a tracing tool and found 32 BTC addresses controlled likely by the same person. One of the addresses is 16S1CGZVbGb2htfDAC1RxxaUo2dQbT6X85 which sent funds to BTC address 16UGGV5p1VobV64xWSgXtaHsveqPPtsWeP which belongs to exmo.com.